# Angularjs: how to do javascript based modification in DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a small angular project, and I would like to modify my view based on some model modifications. However, this is not handled by "ng-xxx" directives but by some specific Javascript code.

What is the pattern to do this?

I have two options:

- call in my controller a global javascript method (which is bad!)
- watch in my main page the variable change and update the view accordingly (a little bit better)

I try to do this to display part of my model on an OpenStreetMap view, but the question is not specific to OSM (or leaflet)

Comment: Can you be more specific about which kind of modification you want to achieve ? Usually ng-show, ng-hide, ng-if, are quite usefull and solve most case.

Comment: I am trying to display part of my models on openstreetmap maps

Comment: You may implement your own directive using this specific javascript